# Translate text in a toastr element

Tags: jquery, ember.js, internationalization

I am new to ember..
In this piece of code I would like to replace the fixed string with a translation:

```
toastr.info('This is the text', '', {
    onclick: () => this.transitionToRoute('user-profile')
});
```

How to replace this with `=> t 'adverts.title'`
Tried all kind of (){} combinations but no success..

Answer (score 0):

if it is i18n you are talking about then try one of these

this.get('i18n').t('adverts.title')

or

t("adverts.title")

Comment: Thanks so far.
first proposal: toastr shows up with no content
second proposal: toastr no show up
Greetings

Comment: 'adverts.title' is it defined in your translation file?

 first proposal: toastr shows up with no content  this should work , this could be because 'adverts.title' is not mapped in your file.

Comment: this.get('i18n').t('toaster.profile').toString()
toString was missing